# How to determine source of a third party dependency to resolve warning

Tags: java, jcr, jackrabbit-oak

I'm trying to resolve the warning below, happening in an outside dependency of my project. What is a good way to find out what dependency these classes are provided in? I'm using Jackrabbit Oak 1.52.0.

The Jackrabbit Oak version I'm using is the most recent available, I'm surprised it would come with warnings. Any other way to resolve this?

Error in the background thread of the persistent cache: java.lang.IllegalStateException: java.lang.AbstractMethodError:
Receiver class org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.plugins.document.persistentCache.KeyDataType
does not define or inherit an implementation of the resolved method 'abstract void write(org.h2.mvstore.WriteBuffer, java.lang.Object[], int, boolean)'
of interface org.h2.mvstore.type.DataType